# Typescript: generate generic keys recursively, concatenating keys and ignoring objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The lib Prisma accepts filters like this:

```
prisma.user.findMany({
     where: {
         name: { contains: 'jeff' },
         city: {
             name: { contains: 'hol' },
             state: { 
                 acr: {
                     equals: 'vegas'
                 }
             }
         }
     }
})
```

By giving the object:

```
{
    name: '',
    city: {
        name: '',
        state: {
           acr: ''
        }
    }
}
```

I want to generate the type:

```
type UserFilters = {
    name_contains?: string,
    name_equals?: string,
    city_name_contains?: string
    city_name_equals?: string
    city_state_acr_contains?: string
    city_state_acr_equals?: string
}
```

I managed to get this:

```
type FilterR<Form> = Form extends object
    ? Partial<{
            [Key in string & keyof Form as `${Key}_${'contains' | 'equals'}`]: FilterR<Form[Key]>
      }>
    : Form
```

That gives me:

```
Partial<{
    name_contains: "";
    name_equals: "";
    city_contains: Partial<{
        name_contains: "";
        name_equals: "";
        state_contains: Partial<{
            acr_contains: "";
            acr_equals: "";
        }>;
        state_equals: Partial<{
            acr_contains: "";
            acr_equals: "";
        }>;
    }>;
    city_equals: Partial<...>;
}>
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mxJPGw) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Is the leaf node always going to be `string`? Could it be `number` or something?  I wish there were some explicit I/O test cases here, like `interface X { ⋯ } interface Y { ⋯ } ⋯` followed by "I want `FilterR<X>` to be ⋯ and `FilterR<Y>` to be ⋯".  These deeply nested types often have bizarre edge cases whose fixes require complete refactoring, so it would be nice to get them out of the way earlier rather than later.

Comment: @wonderflame yes, that's exactly what I was looking for \0/

Comment: @jcalz always strings, I'm not sure what other examples I could come up with without repeating myself. If it is a string then generate 2 keys, one ending with '_contains', the other with '_equals' and if it's an object recursively concatenate the keys until the last one where you generate the same 2 keys

Comment: @LucasSteffen great, will write an answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create a type that will return a type with the following shape:

```
Record<originalKey, updatedKey>
```

`updatedKey` will depend on whether the property under the original key is an object or not. If it is an object then we prepend the original key to the beginning of the updated key with `_` and call the type recursively for the property, otherwise, we will add `'contains' | 'equals'` to the end of the original string. From the shape, we can tell that we need a union of all values, which can be done with the following type:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
```

Let's create a type for the filter:

```
type Filter = 'contains' | 'equals';
```

Type for getting keys:

```
type FilterKeys<T> = ValueOf<{
  [K in keyof T & string]: T[K] extends object
    ? `${K}_${FilterKeys<T[K]>}`
    : `${K}_${Filter}`;
}>;
```

Testing:

```
// "name_contains" | "name_equals" | "city_name_contains" | "city_name_equals" | "city_state_acr_contains" | "city_state_acr_equals"
type A = FilterKeys<typeof obj>;
```

Looks good!

What's left is just to use these keys in a *mapped type*:

```
type FilterR<T> = { [K in FilterKeys<T>]?: string };

// type A = {
//   name_contains?: string | undefined;
//   name_equals?: string | undefined;
//   city_name_contains?: string | undefined;
//   city_name_equals?: string | undefined;
//   city_state_acr_contains?: string | undefined;
//   city_state_acr_equals?: string | undefined;
// }
type A = FilterR<typeof obj>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGYCGAtgKYBcMA5OQDTYzACWUAnmVjjvsWZTezNHiikMtPnmAAnbtVEwAvr3k05MPBDrhoAbkyZmAByIwAqhCISAYvQA2QierRtchIgH1QYKHnqQA-GWgJHwBzHQ4XVyIARwBXPGsIf34oILBQ2gZmV043Dy8fRICUkLC6RiZsiOi4hKTAkozy1wEhV3EJd3B8vyLU9JxMipa3dsjY+MLkvp05HT0mQxgrW3NUCjzvSHIYAB8KaonyOYMjADV4mKIAeQAzAB4AFQA+NYeAbQBrIiYQG5gHgC6OhOJjA9HADxAAElPOYzMAoOCwHdjC80AAKYwwIgADyEYAAJuo8GAmDBfDB0R8yMYAJSoF4ANxA9AJMDIYCIjPM9Nx+KJlNo1JgPhuqyhNHpKCZLIJtApUNoHK55mOCyMyzsAGlvhBHmiYOdrJdbncnG8tSKwDAvj8-g8YAAyKYhAFkd5agHYvFEQnqBCIIgI2QUgAGABJ0Fq5K5I5rzDqmHqPQCnnJQ7IyBGozG4zY7OmZk81Yt4xIAEr6tboGAWq1LfMJ3X6gF1YppeRzTAAem7MBBAEFqz2++FiJ1PJtJvUO3sYoSiDcfEQCTpe+wcmMatP28FdjB5wTF8vVyP2INKuONgU23194fj5zT+uBk1Nwdar0QveF0un2vRzKLJhjaSQJ26Hc7znX8TwA88mhA0YP0g79oKPP8VzguR5kWIc0DLSsTl+OAkGLTAgA)